# NHibernate GetNamedQuery can not execute stored procedure

Tags: nhibernate

So I have a stored procedure named `get_by_cat_and_tag`, it should return table `MS`, and in my C# code it should return a list of `MS` objects, where `MS.hbm.xml` contains the following:

```
<sql-query name="get_by_cat_and_tag">
    <!-- return type must be an NHibernate mapped entity -->
    <return class="MS">

      <return-property column="Id" name="Id" />
      <return-property column="FileName" name="FileName" />
      <return-property column="DisplayTitle" name="DisplayTitle" />
      <return-property column="IsEnabled" name="IsEnabled" />
      <return-property column="MediaType" name="MediaType" />
      <return-property column="Priority" name="Priority" />
      <return-property column="DateCreated" name="DateCreated" />
      <return-property column="DateLastModified" name="DateLastModified" />
      <return-property column="Description" name="Description" />
      <return-property column="ImagePath" name="ImagePath" />

    </return>
    <!--exec get_by_cat_and_tag@categoryId=:catId, @tagId=:tId-->
    exec get_by_cat_and_tag:catId, :tId
</sql-query>
```

All column names returned from this stored procedure are correct and for ease I made them the same.

The data access layer contains the call to the stored procedure:

```
var query = session.GetNamedQuery("get_by_cat_and_tag")
                   .SetParameter("catId", categoryId).SetParameter("tId", tagId)
                   .List<MS>();
```

The exception message:

```
could not execute query

[ exec get_by_cat_and_tag @p0, @p1 ]
Name:catId - Value:130  Name:tId - Value:449
[SQL: exec get_by_cat_and_tag @p0, @p1]

The stack trace:
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name)
   at NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, String name)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetInstanceClass(IDataReader rs, Int32 i, ILoadable persister, Object id, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.InstanceNotYetLoaded(IDataReader dr, Int32 i, ILoadable persister, EntityKey key, LockMode lockMode, String rowIdAlias, EntityKey optionalObjectKey, Object optionalObject, IList hydratedObjects, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetRow(IDataReader rs, ILoadable[] persisters, EntityKey[] keys, Object optionalObject, EntityKey optionalObjectKey, LockMode[] lockModes, IList hydratedObjects, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetRowFromResultSet(IDataReader resultSet, ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, LockMode[] lockModeArray, EntityKey optionalObjectKey, IList hydratedObjects, EntityKey[] keys, Boolean returnProxies)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does `get_by_cat_and_tag(130, 449)` works when called directly in the database? Have you tested it?

Comment: @acdcjunior: it does return the expected records, yes

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a space after the word tag:-

`exec get_by_cat_and_tag:catId, :tId`

should be:-

`exec get_by_cat_and_tag :catId, :tId`

Also note that all columns returned must also match in case, its always worth checking that one.

Comment: the space is just a typo. I have already exactly as you have written it (with a space). The column names are exactly the same.    If I put in my data access layer this: session.CreateSQLQuery("exec [dbo].[get_By_cat_and_tag_Id] :catId, :tagId")
                    .SetInt32("catId", categoryId)
                    .SetInt32("tagId", tagId) It works perfectly well, but I can not make it run the way I have specified as a named query...

Comment: What does the inner exception show?  Also is this a problem with nulls?

Comment: InnerException: media2_2_0_, but this first property under inner exception looks weird: System.indexoutOfRangeException={"media2_2_0_"}

Comment: I take it the `SP` returns 10 columns? Are they in same order as defined in your mapping (and same case)

Comment: They were not in same order, but same case and words... it works fine the createSQLQuery, means order did not play any role. Yet, I have changed that to be exactly same order, same exception is thrown :S

Comment: According to nhprof what is generated SQL and what results do you get back. I can't believe this is a bug.